# Cloth Simulation Not going through Ring

Tags: animation, sculpting, cloth-simulation

Good day,

I'm making a 3D model of a garbage bag holder. Unfortunately, when I got to the plastic bag, I hit a major barrier. I've been trying to make a cloth simulation to make it look like a bag is hanging.

I did a few experiments to see if I could solve the problem on my own. See below a few screenshots of the issue at hand.

This is the garbage bag stand:

[image: The model which will hold the bag]

I tried to sculpt the bag, but it looks terribly as I'm not skilled with the tool. But I though to attach this screenshot as it is a useful picture to show what result I'm trying to get.

[image]

So I started to do experiments with this ring and the floor beneath.

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not go through the ring, but rather rests on it as if it were a table.

[image]

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Karl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about modeling a "folded" bag, make it a Cloth, add a pin group set to the top vertices and apply some simple shapekeys? Here is a quick example:

[image]

With more geometry and some experiment a bit more details can be added...

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to do it now.